# How to append to node created by Jenkins job dsl in same configure block?

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I have some jobDsl that looks like this:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('foo/bar') {
        branchSources {
        git {
            remote('https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git')
            credentialsId('github-ci')
            includes('JENKINS-*')
        }
    }
}
```

which generates the following xml (snippet):

```
<!-- 1. foo/bar -->
<org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject>
    <sources class='jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchSourceList'>
        <data>
            <jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
                <source class='jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMSource'>
                    <id>d45cd641-7223-4b58-9de5-837c3fe584a7</id>
                    <remote>https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git</remote>
                    <credentialsId>github-ci</credentialsId>
                    <includes>JENKINS-*</includes>
                    <excludes></excludes>
                    <ignoreOnPushNotifications>false</ignoreOnPushNotifications>
                </source>
                <strategy class='jenkins.branch.DefaultBranchPropertyStrategy'>
                    <properties class='empty-list'></properties>
                </strategy>
            </jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
        </data>
        <owner class='org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject' reference='../..'></owner>
    </sources>
```

What I would like to do is append a node (call it `traits`) to the `jenkins.branch.BranchSource` node created by the jobDsl multibranchJob api via the configure block:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('foo/bar') {
        branchSources {
        git {
            remote('https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git')
            credentialsId('github-ci')
            includes('JENKINS-*')
        }

            configure {
               def first =  it / 'sources'(class: 'jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchSourceList') / 'data' / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource'
                first << traits {
                    foo('bar')
                }
            }
    }
}
```

However, according to https://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/, the above dsl would create the xml as such:

```
<sources class='jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchSourceList'>
    <data>
        <jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
            <traits>
                <foo>bar</foo>
            </traits>
        </jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
        <jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
            <source class='jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMSource'>
                <id>7fd47865-fffa-4f8f-98f1-ac6de65249f7</id>
                <remote>https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git</remote>
                <credentialsId>github-ci</credentialsId>
                <includes>JENKINS-*</includes>
                <excludes></excludes>
                <ignoreOnPushNotifications>false</ignoreOnPushNotifications>
            </source>
            <strategy class='jenkins.branch.DefaultBranchPropertyStrategy'>
                <properties class='empty-list'></properties>
            </strategy>
        </jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
    </data>
</sources>
```

Basically, is there any way to append to the `BranchSource` node that is created from the `branchSources` call?

Comment: I am not sure if they have introduced anything to accommodate your requirement yet. But one thing you can do is to have the section come from configure block rather having dsl code for it...

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm in a similar situation

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but just had the same problem and it drove me crazy... Looks like moving the configure block to the end of the pipeline definition helps - also using correct XPath tooling.

Fred's blog post bumped me into the correct direction. Go check it out: https://ftclausen.github.io/infra/jenkins/jenkins-jobdsl-git-traits/

**Pipeline Definition**

```
multibranchPipelineJob('foo/bar') {
        branchSources {
        git {
            id("foobar")
            remote('https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git')
            credentialsId('github-ci')
            includes('JENKINS-*')
        } 
    }
    configure {
        def traits = it / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits {
            traits << 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.LocalBranchTrait'{}
        }
   }
}
```

**Resulting config.xml**

```
<sources class='jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchSourceList'>
        <data>
            <jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
                <source class='jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMSource'>
                    <id>foobar</id>
                    <remote>https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git</remote>
                    <credentialsId>github-ci</credentialsId>
                    <includes>JENKINS-*</includes>
                    <excludes></excludes>
                    <ignoreOnPushNotifications>false</ignoreOnPushNotifications>
                    <traits>
                        <jenkins.plugins.git.traits.LocalBranchTrait></jenkins.plugins.git.traits.LocalBranchTrait>
                    </traits>
                </source>
                <strategy class='jenkins.branch.DefaultBranchPropertyStrategy'>
                    <properties class='empty-list'></properties>
                </strategy>
            </jenkins.branch.BranchSource>
        </data>
        <owner class='org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject' reference='../..'></owner>
    </sources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no `configure` method within the `branchSources` context. So the `configure` method from an outer context will be called. In this case from the `multibranchPipelineJob` context. Since the `branchSources` method has not completed by the time the `configure` method is called, no branch source node have been generated and thus the configure block will create a new node.

Try this instead:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('foo/bar') {
  branchSources {
    git {
      remote('https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git')
      credentialsId('github-ci')
      includes('JENKINS-*')
    }
  }
  configure {
    def source =  it / 'sources'(class: 'jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchSourceList') / 'data' / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource'
    source << traits {
      foo('bar')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work sadly. The configure block doesn't append but erases the whole configuration. Still investigating

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?