# Job DSL: How can I add a configure block to a previously generated XML if several such nodes exist?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using the [Active Choices plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) to dynamically generate parameter values. Unfortunately, Job DSL [doesn't support the secure script configuration](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.activeChoiceReactiveReferenceParam). That's why I'm trying to add this using Job DSL's `configure` block.

I use methods which get the job context or parameter context or whatever. But I learned from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825744/how-to-append-to-node-created-by-jenkins-job-dsl-in-same-configure-block) that I can't access the generated XML using `configure` in the same method, since the XML hasn't been generated yet. I hope I unterstood this right - so in my case, I call two methods. The first creates the base Active Choices configuration, the second adds a secure Groovy script.

Note that I'm adding the Groovy script on the fly by reading a Groovy script's source (`Branch` in this case).

```
      factory.freeStyleJob(jobName) {
        ...
        parameters {
          activeChoiceFormattedHtmlParameter delegate, PARAMETER_BRANCH, BRANCH_PARAMETER_DESCRIPTION, PARAMETER_STAGE, PARAMETER_DATABASE
        }
        ...

        activeChoiceFormattedHtmlScript delegate, PARAMETER_BRANCH, Branch
      }
```

And my methods:

```
    static void activeChoiceFormattedHtmlParameter(Object parameterContext, String parameterName, String parameterDescription, String... referencedParameters) {
      parameterContext.with {
        activeChoiceReactiveReferenceParam(parameterName) {
          description(parameterDescription)
          choiceType(CHOICE_TYPE_FORMATTED_HTML)
          referencedParameters.each { referencedParameter(it) }
        }
      }
    }
```

This generates:

```
            <org.biouno.unochoice.DynamicReferenceParameter>
                <name>BRANCH</name>
                <description>...the description...</description>
                <randomName>choice-parameter-12102071997857508</randomName>
                <visibleItemCount>1</visibleItemCount>
                <referencedParameters>STAGE, DATABASE</referencedParameters>
                <choiceType>ET_FORMATTED_HTML</choiceType>
                <omitValueField>false</omitValueField>
                <parameters class="linked-hash-map"/>
            </org.biouno.unochoice.DynamicReferenceParameter>
```

Then the second method:

```
    static void activeChoiceFormattedHtmlScript(Object jobContext, String parameterName, Class scriptClass) {
      jobContext.with {
        configure { node ->
          def parameterNode = node / 'properties' / 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty' / 'parameterDefinitions' / 'org.biouno.unochoice.DynamicReferenceParameter'
          parameterNode << 'script'('class':'org.biouno.unochoice.model.GroovyScript') {
            'secureScript' {
              'script'(ScriptReader.readScript(scriptClass))
              'sandbox'('false')
              'classpath' {
                'entry' {
                  'url'("file:${GROOVY_JAR}")
                }
              }
            }
            'secureFallbackScript' {
              'script'('')
              'sandbox'('false')
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This adds the script:

```
            <org.biouno.unochoice.DynamicReferenceParameter>
                <name>BRANCH</name>
                <description>...the description...</description>
                <randomName>choice-parameter-12102071997857508</randomName>
                <visibleItemCount>1</visibleItemCount>
                <referencedParameters>STAGE, DATABASE</referencedParameters>
                <choiceType>ET_FORMATTED_HTML</choiceType>
                <omitValueField>false</omitValueField>
                <parameters class="linked-hash-map"/>
                <script class="org.biouno.unochoice.model.GroovyScript">
                    <secureScript>
                        <script>...the script...</script>
                        <sandbox>false</sandbox>
                        <classpath>
                            <entry>
                                <url>file:/path/to/my/groovy-library.jar</url>
                            </entry>
                        </classpath>
                    </secureScript>
                    <secureFallbackScript>
                        <script/>
                        <sandbox>false</sandbox>
                    </secureFallbackScript>
                </script>
            </org.biouno.unochoice.DynamicReferenceParameter>
```

And now for my problem: In the second method `configure` selects the first `org.biouno.unochoice.DynamicReferenceParameter`. But since I want to add more parameters, I need to select it by name, not just the first node that was found. Otherwise I always overwrite the script of the first parameter, and all the other parameter will have no Groovy script.

I tried accessing `... / 'org.biouno.unochoice.DynamicReferenceParameter' / 'name' / parameterName` which works, but of course writes into the wrong place and wrecks the `<name>` node.

I also tried using `... / 'org.biouno.unochoice.DynamicReferenceParameter' / 'name' / parameterName` and then `parameterNode.parent`, but this seems to return `null`.

Can anyone give a hint? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to access the required node, even if it feels not very elegant:

```
    ...
    jobContext.with {
      configure { node ->
        def parameterDefinitionsNode = node / 'properties' / 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty' / 'parameterDefinitions'
        def parameters = parameterDefinitionsNode.children().findAll { it.name() == parameterClass }
        for (parameter in parameters) {
          def name = parameter.'name'
          if (name.text() == parameterName) {
            parameter << 'script'('class':'org.biouno.unochoice.model.GroovyScript') {
```